# Получение данных о пользователе в Qt

Tags: linux, windows, qt

Есть ли в Qt способ узнать данные пользователя? В частности мне нужно узнать логин/имя  пользователя зарегестрированное в системе. Если способы есть и они отличаются в Windows и Linux (debian подобных, но, мне кажется, что для Qt/Linux разницы нет), то расскажите оба :)

Comment: Можно пойти через переменные окружения, но вряд ли это 100% переносимый способ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите [здесь](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11951). Увы, но соответствующего компонента в Qt нет.

Comment: Спасибо :) Самое то :)

Answer (score 7):

Я использовал вот такую няшную конструкцию для получения имени:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    #define qUsername QString::fromLocal8Bit (qgetenv ("USERNAME").constData ()).toUtf8 ()
#elif defined(Q_OS_UNIX)
    #define qUsername qgetenv("USER").constData ()
#endif
```

Comment: Во истину няшное и во истину действенное :) Спасибо.

Comment: Суперня! Кавайи!